# JUnit test case not working for JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

MY Actual java class in like this:-

```java
@Component
public class AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParamJdbcTemplate;

    @Value("${EVENT_CYCLE_STATUS_SETTLEMENT_DATE_MANUAL}")
    private String eventCycleStatusSetlDateManual = "";

    public AxonPaymentRequestEventRequest insertCycleEventStatus() throws SQLException {
        log.info("Inside AxonPaymentRequestCycleEventStatusDao - insertCycleEventStatus()--Entry-eventCycleStatusSetlDateManual-"   + eventCycleStatusSetlDateManual);

        SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .withProcedureName(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.INSERT_CYCLE_STATUS_PROCEDURE)
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.SETTLEMENT_DATE_MANUAL, Types.CHAR))
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.DEBUG_FLAG, Types.CHAR))
                .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.ERROR_INFO, Types.CHAR))
                .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.RESULT, Types.CHAR))
                .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.INSERT_ROW_COUNT, Types.INTEGER));

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.SETTLEMENT_DATE_MANUAL,(eventCycleStatusSetlDateManual.equalsIgnoreCase(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.NULL_STRING) ? null : eventCycleStatusSetlDateManual))
                .addValue(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.DEBUG_FLAG, AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.DEBUG_FLAG_VALUE);
        Map<String, Object> result = call.execute(in);
        
        log.info("Inside AxonPaymentRequestCycleEventStatusDao - getCycleEventStatus() - result of INSERT_CYCLE_STATUS_PROCEDURE-" + result);
        
        if (null != result && result.get("RESULT").equals(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.RESULT_PASS)) {
            return getCycleEventStatus();
        } 
        }
    }
}
```

My test class is:-

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDaoTest {

    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Mock
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Mock
    private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;
    
    @InjectMocks
    AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDao axonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDao = new AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDao();

    @Test
    public void testInsertCycleEventStatus() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();
        output.put("RESULT", "PASS");

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(axonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDao, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplate);
        when(simpleJdbcCall.execute(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(output);
        
        Mockito.when(simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.INSERT_CYCLE_STATUS_PROCEDURE)).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCall);
        Mockito.when(simpleJdbcCall.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCall);
        Mockito.when(simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(
                new SqlParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.SETTLEMENT_DATE_MANUAL, Types.CHAR),
                new SqlParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.DEBUG_FLAG, Types.CHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.ERROR_INFO, Types.CHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.RESULT, Types.CHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleConstant.INSERT_ROW_COUNT, Types.INTEGER))).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCall);
        
        Mockito.when(simpleJdbcCall.execute(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(output);
        
        AxonPaymentRequestEventRequest axonPaymentRequestEventRequest = axonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDao.insertCycleEventStatus();
    }
}
```

I am getting exception as:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No DataSource set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:314)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:298)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcCall.java:355)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:370)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:198)
    at com.mastercard.settlment.axon.payment.request.status.dao.AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDao.insertCycleEventStatus(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDao.java:58)
    at com.mastercard.settlment.axon.payment.request.status.dao.AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDaoTest.testInsertCycleEventStatus(AxonPaymentRequestStatusEventCycleDaoTest.java:57)
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: just to provide more insight i am getting the above exception on the line,

Map<String, Object> result = call.execute(in);

Comment: Well, you have `SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)` so you are not mocking `SimpleJdbcCall` but using the real implementation, hence the error. Solutions: https://www.google.com/search?q=simplejdbccall+mockito+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinyb7ZmdDtAhURZcAKHVwaBD4QrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=2560&bih=1297